# Fedora 33 Compile and signing rtl8812 module modprobe rejects with 'Key was rejected by service'

Tags: fedora

[Secure Boot]
[Fedora 33]
[Kernel 5.11.11-200, 64 Bit]
[Kernel-devel 5.11.11-200]
[Kernel-headers 5.11.11-200]
[gcc 10.2.1 20201125]

I have an Edimax Wi-Fi AC600 Bluetooth4.0 USB Adapter and downloaded the source from github (as recommanded from serveral sides). I was able to compile the driver, also to sign the driver but I cannot load it.

As soon as I want to load the module with

**modprobe -f 8812au**

`modprobe reports Key was rejected by service`

The mokutil shows my key as enrolled

```
SHA1 Fingerprint: e3:4c:f5:5c:fd:2b:89:a2:40:9a:33:dd:ad:0b:28:4c:14:4d:c7:6f
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            55:01:a2:74:73:ab:b1:ae:44:a4:f8:e1:e3:ed:43:2a:7e:a3:d1:ce
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: O=weon, CN=weon Signing key/emailAddress=
        Validity
            Not Before: Apr  2 18:37:47 2021 GMT
            Not After : Mar  9 18:37:47 2121 GMT
        Subject: O=weon, CN=weon Signing key/emailAddress=
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
```

What's curios is that the UEFI Bootloader shows two Fedora boot entries (one with shmi.efi and one with shmix64.efi). That's happen after an earlier update of Fedora 32.

Has anybody an idea where to search / what to do?

[EDIT]
**mokutil -l**

shows different RSA Public-Key for **Fedora [2048bits]** and for my key **[4096bits]**

Comment: What does `modprobe -v 8812au` show?

Comment: Do other signed modules have the same problem?  I'm still on F32 and have kernel 5.11.11-100 with the same Edimax Wi-FI dongle and https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git branch v5.6.4.2 works fine after signing/modprobe.  One difference of note, my module is named `88XXau.ko`.  I wonder why yours has a different name.

Comment: I tried aircrack-ng with DKMS and signing but I get the same results.

**modprobe 8812au**

results in 

`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Exec format error`

with

**modprobe -f 8812au**

I get

`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Key was rejected by service`

Comment: If you are using aircrack-ng, where is `8812au.ko` coming from?  After I build the aircrack-ng module, it is literally called `88XXau.ko`.  I am using branch `v5.6.4.2` - which branch are you using?  Have you tried building/signing/modprobing `88XXau.ko`?  Do you have a signing problem?  Can you successfully sign and modprobe other modules?

Comment: At least with my compiler configuration it will create the 8812au.ko (or 8812au.ko.xz with dkms). 

But the other thing is that if I use another Fedora 32 (virtual machine) to compile/sign the module can be loaded but not with my physical machine

Comment: Sorry, I guess my hardware and system are too different from yours.  The aircrack driver works great for me and is easily compiled/installed/signed/modprobed.  I don't know why your experience is so different.  Good luck!